# How to most efficiently repeat the same merge on different columns in R (preferably data.table)

Tags: r, performance, merge, data.table, processing-efficiency

I have program that needs to repeat a merge which uses the same column from Table A over and over, but changes the column from table B. Doing it with a loop that uses the data.table::merge command repeatedly is quite slow, so I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do it.

For an example:

Imagine a table "A" of fruits, with two columns, "fruit_name" and "price."

And another table "B" of baskets, with 3 columns, "fruit_1", "fruit_2", and "fruit_3"

I would like to get the sum price of the fruits in table B for each row. I could do 3 merges, all using "fruit_name" from the fruit table, and the first using "fruit_1", second "fruit_2", and 3rd "fruit_3" from the baskets table.

Merges take a long time, though. Is there anyway to do this more efficiently computationally? Here is the code laying out the example and getting the desired result, but doing it too slowly.

I generally use data.table and it's generally efficient, so I prefer a data.table solution but open to others if they are faster than 3 merges.

Also, I imagine I could get the data in long format and do one merge, *ideally* I'd avoid that,because my data makes a lot of sense in wide format, comes in wide, and needs to be exported wide. But if it's definitely the best practice then I guess that's good to know.

Thanks all for your time!

Edit: I chose the answer that I did because for my use case, at least, its limitations are not a problem. And, it is very, very fast.

The more upvoted answer takes a bit longer to do the initial melt step than the chosen one takes to do the whole task. So, for speed alone, I think the chosen answer is best, if it works for you.

If it doesn't, then the most upvoted answer is probably good!

```
library(data.table)


fruits <- data.table(fruit_name = c('orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'kiwi', 'blueberry')
                     , price = c(1, 1.531, 2.1, 2.25, 3.03)
                     )

baskets <- data.table(fruit_1 = c('orange', 'apple', 'apple', 'pear')
                      ,fruit_2 = c('apple', 'pear', 'kiwi', 'kiwi')
                      ,fruit_3 = c('pear', 'kiwi', 'blueberry', 'blueberry'))

result <- copy (baskets)


result <- merge(result, fruits, by.x = 'fruit_1', by.y = 'fruit_name')
setnames(result, 'price', 'price_1')

result <- merge(result, fruits, by.x = 'fruit_2', by.y = 'fruit_name')
setnames(result, 'price', 'price_2')

result <- merge(result, fruits, by.x = 'fruit_3', by.y = 'fruit_name')
setnames(result, 'price', 'price_3')

result[,price_total := price_1 + price_2 + price_3]
```

Comment: Some benchmarks here: https://gist.github.com/iangow/5b2ff852ea19d7b73f92fa2d682dfb4e

It is difficult to beat the accepted answer for performance here. DuckDB does pretty well, however. If the data were coming from a database in the first place, this approach might be the winner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the function `chmatch` from data.table, you can solve your problem as follow. If it is still slow, replace `chmatch` with the function `collapse::fmatch` and check if there is some performance improvement.

```
baskets[, price_total := rowSums(sapply(.SD, \(x) fruits$price[chmatch(x, fruits$fruit_name)])), .SDcols=patterns("fruit")]

#    fruit_1 fruit_2   fruit_3 price_total
#     <char>  <char>    <char>       <num>
# 1:  orange   apple      pear       4.631
# 2:   apple    pear      kiwi       5.881
# 3:   apple    kiwi blueberry       6.811
# 4:    pear    kiwi blueberry       7.380
```

Comment: This worked because the matches are rectangular. But that is not necessarily the case. ie you might have a column with only apple, or with only pear, or with no matches and this method will fail

Answer (score 4):

directly use `data.table`:

```
baskets[, melt(.SD, measure.vars = patterns('fruit'),value.name = 'fruit_name')
    ][fruits, on = 'fruit_name'
    ][, price := sum(price), by = rowid(variable)
    ][, dcast(.SD, rowid(variable)+price~variable, value.var = 'fruit_name')]

   variable price fruit_1 fruit_2   fruit_3
1:        1 4.631  orange   apple      pear
2:        2 5.881   apple    pear      kiwi
3:        3 6.811   apple    kiwi blueberry
4:        4 7.380    pear    kiwi blueberry
```

Comment: I added some code at the end of my answer to make a bigger version of `baskets` (100,000 baskets of 30 items each). The `data.table` code provided by @Onyambu takes ~1 second and the `dplyr` code I provided takes ~2 seconds. Behind the scenes, they're doing similar things (`melt` and `pivot_longer`; `dcast` and `pivot_wider`), but my answer adds translation overhead for the computer and---if you know `data.table`---for you.

Comment: @IanGow

Nice, thanks for the extra info, super helpful! 

I'm adapting it now for my stuff and will be curious to see how it compares. I could have mentioned in teh question, I have ~8,000,000 rows of baskets with ~8 fruits in each. The separate merges take ~8 seconds.

I was worried about the overhead cost of doing the reshape before the single merge, but let me try it now and see. I guess it should make it faster, let's see how much!

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with `data.table`. But the following might give you some ideas (I am using `dtplyr` so that `dplyr` works on `data.table`).

I think that pivoting to a long format and summarising should give you good performance. Packages like `DuckDB` and `rpolars` can beat even `data.table` for performance for this kind of thing (though `data.table` should be fast).

Note that I am inferring from the summing across rows that the rows  represent "baskets".

Getting back to wide form is not difficult.

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(dtplyr)
library(tidyr)

fruits <- data.table(fruit_name = c('orange', 'apple', 'pear', 'kiwi', 
                                    'blueberry'), 
                     price = c(1, 1.531, 2.1, 2.25, 3.03)
)

baskets <- data.table(fruit_1 = c('orange', 'apple', 'apple', 'pear')
                      ,fruit_2 = c('apple', 'pear', 'kiwi', 'kiwi')
                      ,fruit_3 = c('pear', 'kiwi', 'blueberry', 'blueberry'))

baskets_long <-
    baskets |>
    mutate(basket_id = row_number()) |>
    pivot_longer(cols = -basket_id, 
                 values_to = "fruit_name") |>
    separate_wider_delim(name, "_", 
                         names = c("category", "pos")) 

merged <-
    baskets_long |>
    inner_join(fruits, by = "fruit_name")

vals <-
    merged |> 
    group_by(basket_id) |>
    summarize(price_total = sum(price))

baskets_long |> 
    pivot_wider(names_from = c("category", "pos"), 
                values_from = "fruit_name", 
                names_glue = "{category}_{pos}") |>
    inner_join(vals)
#> Joining with `by = join_by(basket_id)`
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#>   basket_id fruit_1 fruit_2 fruit_3   price_total
#>       <int> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>           <dbl>
#> 1         1 orange  apple   pear             4.63
#> 2         2 apple   pear    kiwi             5.88
#> 3         3 apple   kiwi    blueberry        6.81
#> 4         4 pear    kiwi    blueberry        7.38
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(tidyr)

fruits <- data.table(fruit_name = c('orange', 'apple',
                                    'pear', 'kiwi', 'blueberry')
                     , price = c(1, 1.531, 2.1, 2.25, 3.03)
)

get_basket <- function(i) {
  tibble(id = i, 
         fruit = sample(fruits$fruit_name, basket_size, replace = TRUE))
}

basket_size <- 30L
num_baskets <- 100000L
baskets_long <- 
  bind_rows(lapply(1:num_baskets, get_basket)) |>
  group_by(id) |>
  mutate(item_no = row_number()) |>
  ungroup()
  

baskets_tbl <- pivot_wider(baskets_long, id_cols = "id", 
                           values_from = "fruit",
                           names_from = "item_no",
                           names_glue = "fruit_{item_no}")

baskets <- data.table(baskets_tbl)
```

Comment: Note that if you add `basket_id` to the original `baskets` data set, there should be no need to `pivot_wider()`. Just join `baskets` with `vals`.